# QGIS does not show 3D models with textures in 3D map view

Tags: qgis, 3d, 3d-model

### The problem

When I load 3D models (Wavefront `.obj` files) to QGIS 3.22 on Win10, they show up correctly in 3D view, but only when `Shading` is set to `Realistic (Phong)` or `CAD (Gooch)`. When I select `Embedded Textures`, the model disappeats. I tried different models, between else [this one](https://plugins.qgis.org/wavefronts/16/) created in [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/rV0m_YN84Q0) especially for QGIS by @Klas Karlsson (see at the bottom of this answer for more details).

The problem seems to be QGIS specific, as the same tree model shows correctly colored in Windows 3D viewer on the same machine as well as in Blender.

I tried this on different computers (all Win 10) and encountered the same problem everywhere. So I guess there must be a (QGIS?) setting that I miss.

### The question

How can the 3D model be visualized in QGIS including the textures? It should look like in the linked [video tutorial at 48:07](https://youtu.be/rV0m_YN84Q0?t=2887).

---

### Update:

I followed the steps in the [great tutorial](https://youtu.be/rV0m_YN84Q0) by Klas Karlsson. I downloaded the 3D tree model he created [from here](https://plugins.qgis.org/wavefronts/16/), unpacked and saved all files to the same folder. Using QGIS 3.22.1-Białowieża on WIN 10, it shows with Shading set either to `Realistic (Phong)` or `CAD (Gooch)`. As soon as I switch to `Embedded Textures`, the model disappears:

*Model showing up in `Realistic (Phong)` Shading:*
[image]

*Model does not show in`Embedded Textures` Shading - no other changes were made:*
[image]

*Folder containing the downloaded files:*
[image]

Comment: Does it really only support .obj? A modern format like gltf/glb would probably be a easier choice, if it is supported.

Comment: What is QGIS version? It works in QGIS 3.22.0-Białowieża (Ubuntu). https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcArM.png

Comment: Tried again with QGIS 3.22.1-Białowieża on WIN 10 with the tree model created by Klas Karlsson here: https://youtu.be/rV0m_YN84Q0 and downloaded from here: https://plugins.qgis.org/wavefronts/16/ - Still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am from the GIS side so not a 3D expert, but I did work with 3D files with production based on QGIS process. Sometimes 3D definition could be messy : depending on the software you use, there could be inside and outside flipped or no inside face or the mtl file could not be found.

Use a truck model from the [threebox repository archive](https://github.com/peterqliu/threebox/tree/master/examples/models). It is simple model and it is small (about 3 m long) so you can use scale 10x to see it easily.

It should show up like this :

[image]

Then if it work you could go back to your model and try to fix your material definition. As MTL are text file, you could open and edit them. The structure is simple ([wikipedia can help you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Texture_maps)) and the link with the obj is the material name. Foreach material there is a definition in your mtl file. Here is an example for the window material in the truck.

```
newmtl Window
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.362586 0.585789 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Troubleshooting step by step (if one doesn't work well try the next) :

1. Search for `.jpg` in your mtl file. For each one verify the link to your jpg is correct.  Some path definition could be OS or software dependent.
2. Move the jpg file in the same folder with mtl and obj and then change the link defined in your mtl.
3. For every line where a jpg file is called add `#` to mark the line as comment and get no maping texture.
4. Replace material by material, the definition to be the same as the window material definition above. It is important you keep the material name to link  it with your material used in the obj file. For each material test if you see it is working in QGIS.
5. Try to change the opacity `d` to be `0.5` to view through your 3D model and understand why it doesn't work.

If nothing works : start considering that a truck could be a good model for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm still struggling to ge tthe truck visible - loaded the model, but not even with CAD or Phong it shows up (scaled 10 times)...

Comment: As you succed to see the other model wich CAD or Phong you should be able to see the truck at some scale. As the truck is really small you could try 1000 scale and zoom in out to be sure to see it. May be verify you use metric projection. Which version of QGIS do you use ? Have you tried to open your file in the windows 3D model viewer ?

Comment: I work with QGIS 3.22 on Win 10. Just to make sure I make the settings correctly, see here a screenshot - even with scal of 1000, nothing shows up: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IHB1e.png - Replacing the link to the obj file with the initial model of the house (as in my screenshot), it shows up correctly.

Comment: As I am able to visualize the house model in 3D, it seems promising to try there. That's why I edited my question to add the content of the `.mtl` file. I tried your steps 1,2,and 5, with no success. Steps 3 and 4 are to **hide** some of the textures, if I understood you correctly - so this will not be a solution to **show** textures, right?

Comment: Fine ! Thanks for the mtl file. If you try step 3 the jpg file will not be taken in account but the rest of the texture description should be used. You should see a grey texture. If so then it mean there is no other problem from your mtl file. It mean that the issue is only the link with jpg file that doesn't work. I think you can put the three jpg file in the mtl folder. Then delete '[path]\' of map_Ka map_Kd sentance.

Comment: There is 3 jpg files used in the mtl file "Farm_house_D" "House_Side_D" "Roof_D" but you did talk about 2 jpg files in your folder.

Comment: thanks for your efforts! I will test it as soon as I will have the time to do. The bounty is for sure rewarded. Will let the answer as unaccepted for the moment to see if there are further answers. Final aim is to have the jpgs showing up.

Comment: As you can see from the updated answer, still no success. I ask myself if this could be a windows issue? Are you working with Linux?

Comment: I work on windows too. When you open the file in windows 3d viewer is it ok or not ?

Comment: Yes, no problem in Windows 3D viewer, just in QGIS