# Making 3d layer Symbol transparent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, 3d

I want to display a [3d symbol](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413582/showing-3d-models-in-qgis-3d-map-view-including-textures) (from .obj file) yet make it of single transparent color. How to do such a thing in QGIS 3.22 or later?

Can one inherit [a Material class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractMaterialSettings.html) say from python for example and allow setting of transparency?

Comment: *QGIS 3.22 or later* :) So, you probably expect that your question will be answered in the future :)

Comment: @Taras: yeah kind of seen this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29173 yet hoped for some ad-hock solution for example from python code (because in C++ qgis implementation it seems like nothing really stops API from passing RGBA colour values...)

Comment: @DuckQueen. The comment according tor the answer confuses me a little bit. Where does the 3D map aspect comes from. It does not appear in your question. I Is it intended to render a 3D map scene with transparent objects based on `.obj`. files?

Comment: From original  3d symbol question post

Answer (score 2):

May be you can handle the transparency in Blender directly and render your symbol aftermath. Blender has much more material rendering capabilities,a python API and supports scripting and RGBA for the export. So some automation could be achieved.

### Step by step interactive approach for a skeleton of a Mammoth in the plains without background (certain transparency) as a starting point.

The result should be something like that, drawn by QGIS:

[image]

The idea is to combine two tools. You could use Blender to store the `.obj` and render the object to a `.png`.

#### 1. OBJ-file and Blender import

Example: I use a Mammoth `.obj` from the [Smithonian](https://3d.si.edu/object/3d/mammuthus-primigenius-blumbach:341c96cd-f967-4540-8ed1-d3fc56d31f12

Open Blender and Import the file:

`File ⇨ Import ⇨ Wavefront (.obj)`

[image: Import OBJ]

#### 2. Rendering

Choose the `Cycles Render` here and render the image:

[image: Render first]

Set the render options and render again with F12 or Render:

[image: Setup and Render again]

**Note: Much more options on the objects, light conditions, cameras etc. of the rendering scene can applied here. You could have the full potential of the Blender 3D editor , scene configuration and rendering.I changed the light source to sun for example, to get an brighter image.**

*Advise: The Freestyle SVG engine does not work well.*

[image: Sun light source]

#### 3. Storage and problems with crop

Choose `Image ⇨ Save As Image`

[image: Storage]

For some reason the crop did not work for me ..I use gimp to crop it again.

#### 4. QGIS application

Open QGIS an create a point layer and choose the a `Raster Image Marker` to render the point symbol:

[image: QGIS Setup]

#### 5. Result

So you have a dead mammoth on the planes:

[image: Result QGIS]

### Python in Blender and QGIS

Th combine the both approaches, you could use the [Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html) with  the [QGIS API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/) to create your specialized symbology.

#### EDIT:

So partial transparency defined in the alpha channel seems to work with PNG symbols.

[image: Transparent parts]

Note: In my personal opinion is the approach to render 3D maps or landscapes within QGIS is a little bit up-side-down, due to the terrific 3D rendering capabilities of Blender, the fact that GIS data could be stuffed into Blender and the `.obj` related symbol rendering can run inside the Blender Engine. This approach seems to be present and done [before](https://wesleybarrgis.wordpress.com/2020/05/19/how-to-make-a-3d-map-in-blender/). A mixture of GIS rendered maps, DEM's and 3D objects in Blender for the creation of 3D maps or landscapes is obviously also becoming practical.

Comment: Yeah... My problem is that one can not see such object on 3d map as 3d elephant=)

Comment: Yes but it is an elephant with an defined geo-position rendered there with QGIS  ;-). If you shade parts of your 3D object in  Blender with a certain transparency  [buzzword alpha transparent textures](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-alpha-transparent-textures-in-blender/) and render the PNG with RGBA it should work.